# C#: What happens to the FileSystemWatcher after watched folder is deleted

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am using `FileSystemWatcher`s for some of the code I am developing.  I do have one question though, what happens to an FSW when the folder it is watching is deleted?

My usecase is this:

1. User creates directory Foo
2. My code then watches Foo using and FSW
3. User deletes Foo
4. Later on, user recreates the Foo directory.

In this case, what happens to the original FSW?  Will it still watch the new directory, or will I have to create a new one?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: No, the FSW will not *automatically* watch "Foo" after its been recreated.**

---

The easiest way is to verify it is to test it out, so I did.

If you use an instance of `FileSystemWatcher` to watch a directory "Foo", and then delete that directory that is being watched, then the `FileSystemWatcher` stops watching that directory.

Even after recreating a directory with the same name "Foo", the `FileSystemWatcher` will no longer raise events for any changes in that directory.

After "Foo" is deleted and recreated, trying to "reset" the `FileSystemWatcher` by setting its `Path` property to "Foo" and `EnableRaisingEvents` property to true does not work consistently - it works correctly the first time around, but fails to do so if "Foo" is deleted and recreated a second time around. (This was tested in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition).

Sadly, it appears that in such a case, the only consistent way of making the `FileSystemWatcher` work as expected is to create a new instance of the `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: That is interesting. I am not doing this for deletion specifically, but any kind of access error (network cable unplugged, etc), and it seems to work multiple times in a row. The odd behavior I found was that if it fails setting `EnableRaisingEvents` true, it remains true. Thus, I must set it false since I'm verifying things are OK with the network partially by it being true.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN Says :

> Some common occurrences, such as copying or moving a file or directory, do not correspond directly to an event, but these occurrences do cause events to be raised. When you copy a file or directory, the system raises a Created event in the directory to which the file was copied, if that directory is being watched. If the directory from which you copied was being watched by another instance of FileSystemWatcher, no event would be raised. For example, you create two instances of FileSystemWatcher. FileSystemWatcher1 is set to watch "C:\My Documents", and FileSystemWatcher2 is set to watch "C:\Your Documents". If you copy a file from "My Documents" into "Your Documents", a Created event will be raised by FileSystemWatcher2, but no event is raised for FileSystemWatcher1. Unlike copying, moving a file or directory would raise two events. From the previous example, if you moved a file from "My Documents" to "Your Documents", a Created event would be raised by FileSystemWatcher2 and a Deleted event would be raised by FileSystemWatcher1.

Comment: That tells m how events are raised, but it doesn't tell me anything about what happens to an "orphaned" FSW after the Directory it's been watching has been deleted.